# Animate change width of android RelativeLayout

Tags: android, animation

I need to change the width of a RelativeLayout from 0 to 600px programmatically, in an animated way. I'm using the following code:

```
Animation a = new Animation() {
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams drawerParams = (LayoutParams) drawer.getLayoutParams();
        drawerParams.width = 600;
        drawer.setLayoutParams(drawerParams);
    }
};

a.setDuration(1000); //Animate for 1s
layout.startAnimation(a);
```

However, for some reason this isn't working. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I just typed this up and works perfect here

**Animation**

```
public class ResizeWidthAnimation extends Animation {
    private int mWidth;
    private int mStartWidth;
    private View mView;
    
    public ResizeWidthAnimation(View view, int width) {
        mView = view;
        mWidth = width;
        mStartWidth = view.getWidth();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        int newWidth = mStartWidth + (int) ((mWidth - mStartWidth) * interpolatedTime);

        mView.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
        mView.requestLayout();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**usage**

```
if (animate) {
    ResizeWidthAnimation anim = new ResizeWidthAnimation(leftFrame, leftFragmentWidthPx);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    leftFrame.startAnimation(anim);
} else {
    this.leftFragmentWidthPx = leftFragmentWidthPx;
    LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) leftFrame.getLayoutParams();
    lp.width = leftFragmentWidthPx;
    leftFrame.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

***UPDATE: Kotlin Version***

```kotlin
class ResizeWidthAnimation(private val mView: View, private val mWidth: Int) : Animation() {
    private val mStartWidth: Int = mView.width

    override fun applyTransformation(interpolatedTime: Float, t: Transformation) {
        mView.layoutParams.width = mStartWidth + ((mWidth - mStartWidth) * interpolatedTime).toInt()
        mView.requestLayout()
    }

    override fun willChangeBounds(): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it just me or changing duration has no effect?

Comment: It some times work sometimes does not. Is it just me :)

Comment: Always in the same layout? It might work different in linear vs relative layout, i'am not really sure either, it is pretty old code by now and haven't used it myself in a while either.

Comment: It could be better if you would mention some value of animate, leftframe and leftframewidthpx

Comment: Look at the implementation of the animation object. It expects a view (you want to animate a view, so that should probably be the view you provide) and you want to change the width (is of type int) so make it 300 and your view will become 300 width.

Comment: what is the function of this if statement?
if(animate) how and when the value of this animate variable will be changed? can you please guide me

Comment: Simply part of a function that layouts the the items animated or not. 'public void layoutComponent(boolean animated) { .... }

Answer (score 4):

A lot of times the easiest way to animate layout changes in Android is to set the `animateLayoutChanges` attribute to `true` in the layout xml. For more details, see http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `setLayoutParams()`, call `requestLayout()` after the width change.

Comment: Do I do this outside of the applyTransformation method or inside?

Comment: of course it dosn`t works... 
this is how to set layout sizes.
      int newWidth = originalWidth + (int) ((this.newWidth - originalWidth) * interpolatedTime);


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth, this.newHeight);
        mView.setLayoutParams(parms);
        mView.requestLayout();

Comment: Calling `setLayoutParams()` is enough. It calls `requestLayout()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
public class CloseImageFromRightToLeft extends Animation {
    private final int newWidth;
    private final int newHeight;
    private final int originalWidth;
    private ImageView mView;

    public CloseImageFromRightToLeft(ImageView v, int[] widthAndHeight) {
        mView = v;
        this.newWidth = widthAndHeight[0] / 3;
        this.originalWidth = widthAndHeight[0];
        this.newHeight = widthAndHeight[1];
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        int newWidth = originalWidth + (int) ((this.newWidth - originalWidth) * interpolatedTime);


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth, this.newHeight);
        mView.setLayoutParams(parms);
        mView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```