# Move view to above off other view

Tags: android

i have a view in my activity and i want to set above of other view programmatically with animation in runtime.

Im trying to get location on screen but it gives me wrong values..

Anyone knows other way?

Answer (score 0):

Try it With     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams and add add a Rule: LayoutParams.Above where the anchor is the view which should be below..

and add this Params  to your view. I didn't tried it because I'm on the phone. But maybe it gives you a direction till i'm at home. Then if you want I can provide code to support you in a better way. Hope it fits your needs.

Try this:

[Animate change width of android RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641539/animate-change-width-of-android-relativelayout)

Or this :

[Android - Change left margin using animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881419/android-change-left-margin-using-animation)

With LayoutParams above instead of width or height. Didn't try it hope it helps...

Comment: I need to use it to move with a animation, how can i convert LayoutParams to deltas or absolute positions..?

Comment: @colymore you didn't write that in your question. please update your question to get better support. I will think of a solution for your issue