# ImageView change width animation

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I'm trying to make animation on ImageView to change it's width but nothing happened

this is my code

```
final ImageView NewsDeitalHeaderImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.NewsDeitalHeaderImage);
     NewsDeitalHeaderImage.setImageResource(NewsDeitalSharedImage);

     ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(  NewsDeitalHeaderImage.getMeasuredWidth() , WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
         anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
         @Override
         public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
             int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)NewsDeitalHeaderImage.getLayoutParams();
             layoutParams.width =val;
             NewsDeitalHeaderImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
         }
     });
     anim.setDuration(300);
     anim.start();
```

Comment: Could you please try the code stated at this link.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17200611/1458397

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use wrong value for final width. `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` returns **-1** by default, that's why you don't have a proper animation. So I guess you need to use `getParent().getMeasuredWidth()` method of `NewsDeitalHeaderImage` to get the proper final width value:

```
...
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(NewsDeitalHeaderImage.getMeasuredWidth(), NewsDeitalHeaderImage.getParent().getMeasuredWidth());
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        // your code here for animation
    }
});
...
```